# POST Method API Missing Fields

Tags: json, api, post, airtable

I am getting an error when using POST to Airtable in Postman client. I am copying the example exactly from the API documentation and changing the authorization key.

GET method is working.

Why is this?

I have tried changing the content type, modifying the fields, but nothing worked.

$ curl -v -XPOST https://api.airtable.com/v0/appLAzbce9A4J7prZ/TestTable 
-H "Authorization: REDACTED" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{
"fields": {
"Pharmacy": "Test",
"PID": "18101",
"Transaction": "123231"
},
"typecast": true
}'

The POST method should update my AirTable spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely remove your access token from this page and then reset your access token in your Airtable account settings.  You can do that by going to account settings and clicking the "Regenerate API Key" button.

I think the problem with your cURL command is that you are doing `-XPOST` but it should be `-X POST` (see the extra space).  I was able to succesfully complete a call by adding that extra space.  For more info, you can review cURLs command line options at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X.

Within Postman though, you should never have to write the raw cURL request.  Instead, make sure you have the right method type and URL in the top bar. Then, you can define your request body.  I always do `raw` and make sure that the type is set to `JSON (application/json)`. This will also added the right content-type header to the request. Finally, you should make sure you are adding the `Authorization` header to the request.  The `Authorization` header should be "Bearer {access_token}" where `{access_token}` is your Airtable API key.

You can see an example of my Postman environment in the attached screenshot:
[image]